# Iron Man HUD CSS Animation

Tags: html, css, animate.css

I've always been inspired by the HUD display in Iron Man. Specifically how the icons fly in at the initial loading of the suit like here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ZwOxM0-byvc

However, I haven't found a way in CSS get the images to start at the center of the page, drop to the bottom and then slide into their respective spots. I figured that I would have to use something like this:

```
from {
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform:  translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.055, 0.675, 0.190);
}

60% {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1);
}

to{
    left: 0%

}
```

However, when I do that it creates a weird jitter as it doesn't appear to know how to make the transition smoothly from left center (50% absolute) to then it's respective placement on the page.

Ideas?